# swagger.json uri mapping does not work in Silex app

Tags: silex

I am developing a REST api using PHP and Silex and Swagger.  In a local development environment I am trying to map the uri http://localhost:8888/swagger.json to the swagger spec.  However, the silex routing mechanism in a local dev mode does not seem to like uri's that end with ".json".  I can get this to work when I deploy the application to an http server, but not in local dev mode.  Does anyone know if this is a config issue in Silex?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants to refer to this later.  I found a solution.  To get this to work in my project, which is based on the Silex skeleton project (https://silex.symfony.com/download).  The skeleton project includes web/index_dev.php.  I created a task in my composer file that runs the php local/dev server for the project using that file.  The task looks like this:

php -S localhost:8888 -t web /web/index_dev.php

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem can be found at:

https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/web_servers.html#php-5-4

Look near the bottom of the page for the "PHP" section.